# json.decode doesn't find the values of a json

Tags: lua, json

Here is my part of the code that decode json:

```
local bests = json.decode(event.response)
print(event.response)
```

and it prints in the console

```
[{"id":"73","userID":"2","userName":"Test","userLastname":"Test","score":"3"}]
```

but when I am trying the following:

`print(bests.userName)` returns nil

`print(bests[0].userName)` error

```
print(bests.userName[0]) error
```

I've try any combination and it doesn't seem to work, what is my mistake?

Comment: Lua arrays start with index 1.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thanks Egor, that was the problem. I am a C++ guy, I didn't expect that.

Answer (score 1):

As Egor already replied [in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466786/json-decode-doesnt-find-the-values-of-a-json#comment28868565_19466786), indexing starts with `1` in Lua. For future references though, while debugging the program, you *should* use [an iterator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-pairs) to find out how the table is stored.

```
for k, v in pairs(bests) do
    print( k, v )
end
```